# I got error in Bootstrap media query please guide me through right code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 380px){
    body{
        background: red;
    }
}
```

I am trying to change the body background color to red using `@media screen size 0px to 380px`. But the background color is changing from 0px to 280px. I have gone through the everything in code but i didn't notice how to correct it. please explain me what's wrong happened ?

[image]

Comment: You must have zoomed in the screen. Try ctrl + 0. Might it works let me know if it doesn't work for you

Comment: No need to add `(min-width: 0px)` you can use only max-width here `@media only screen and (max-width:380px){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the test snippet demonstrates that everything is working fine. Try to log the window width like below to see its real size

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
$('#current_width').html($(window).width())
})
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 380px){
    body{
        background: red;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 380px){
    body{
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
Hi there!
<div id='current_width'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try these one,

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 380px) {
body { background-color:red; }
}
```

and pls comment if its work or not.